# android: how to access browser cookie from within app's webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview

let's say I visit some dedicated website www.mysite.com, that placed a cookie in my browser.
later, I want to use that cookie from within some app that opens a webview to the same website, so I can somehow correlate the activity that he user had done via the browser, and the activity he is now doing from within the native app's WebView.

Is it possible to share cookies like that?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to share cookies like that?

No, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: so, for example, if I login to some website using Facebook Connect, it will not "remember" me if I try to access the same website through a native app's WebView later?

Comment: What about different webviews? CookieManager is a singleton in Android. Is it singleton sandboxed by the app instance, or it's a global system-wide singleton?

Comment: @AAverin: `CookieManager` "manages the cookies used by an application's `WebView` instances". Barring some security flaw, there is no way for `CookieManager` to access cookies from some other app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I expected that, it's just not really mentioned anywhere in the docs.  Still, it seems to be shared between app WebView instances, that's good to remember in case same cookie needs to have different values on different WebView instances

Answer (score 0):

Now with OkHttpClient, you  can send a request to a browser and access its cookies

Comment: You may miss the question. It was about a cookie accepted in a browser (Chrome or Safari, etc.) other than the app, which may use OkHttpClient though.